# Python: Custom DSL or custom language inside python

Tags: python

I'm looking to write a simple controller using a raspi. I want to do something like this that allows me to easily do things based on other things

```
if temp > 80
then
   turn_off lights_1
   turn_off lights_2
end
```

Something along those lines that doesn't expose python code and using something easy.

I'm open to all suggestions. thanks!

Comment: Check if IFTTT works for you: https://ifttt.com/. If it does then you can use their REST API via python's `requests` package.

Comment: Its for an aquarium and the items there don't have ifttt support. You can interface through things via a voltage controller and changes in voltage determine how things run.